# Need to load bitcoin wallet on bitcoin-core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have retrieved the private key (bitcoin wallet) that I had stored somewhere a couple of years ago. Now I am trying to load it to bitcoin core but doesn't seem to work.

Stored the key into `wallet.dat` inside `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin` and tried rescanning it, but doesn't seem to work `/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt -rescan`

Any sort of assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import a private key into a pruned node?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99681/how-can-i-import-a-private-key-into-a-pruned-node)

Comment: Close Bitcoin Core, move the wallet into the wallets sub dir inside the Bitcoin Application Support dir, boot Bitcoin Core, ask it to load the wallet, it will complain that there is no BerkeleyDB support.